# How can I use Http Client API(since java 9) in Java8 project

Tags: java, java-8, java-9, http2, java-http-client

Java 9 imports a new  HTTP/2 Client API which seems good to use but is there any way to use it in Java 8?

OR

Is there any `shim`/`polyfill`(from javascript) available to make it available in Java 8?

Comment: In case you are still interested here is a Java 8 backport: https://github.com/stefan-zobel/http2client-java8 (I'm the maintainer of this project)

Answer (score 6):

**Is there any way to use it in java 8?**

**No**, because the [`jdk.incubator.http`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/package-summary.html) module has been added *since Java 9*.

So it wouldn't be possible to compile it with a `--release 8` option on the compiler work with Java8. You would end up getting errors as:

> ```
> $ javac --release 8 .../src/com/HttpGet.java 
>
> $ .../src/com/HttpGet.java:3: error: package jdk.incubator.http does not exist
> import jdk.incubator.http.HttpClient;
>                          ^
> ```

---

With minimal code to reproduce this as:-

```
import jdk.incubator.http.HttpClient;

public class HttpGet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder().followRedirects(HttpClient.Redirect.ALWAYS).build();
        System.out.println(httpClient.version());
    }
}
```

---

Moreover, the documentation clearly reads this upfront

> **[Incubating Feature](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/11). Will be removed in a future release.**

Comment: it's not *removal 100% of the time*, it might be simply *finalized* and left into idk after all; just a small wording issue I guess

Comment: @Eugene Indeed. I quoted the javadoc linked though..it happens to be that it contradicts the thought behind the Incubator JEP.

Comment: since the incubating feature is mostly implemented by java source code, I tried to copy and compile it to a jar by myself, but the Java 8 compiler complained there is some internal API is missing...
The missing API is like `System.Logger`, `...misc.Unsafe`, `AsnycResult` etc.

Comment: @IanHu Not sure of what you copied. But eventually there is a possibility that a lot of it might be depending on internal APIs which might not again be available in Java8. Also do note the point of consuming such APIs with License. ;)

Comment: @Eugene When finalized, at least the package names will change (moving from `jdk.incubator` to `java.something`), so these specific packages _will_ be removed.

Answer (score 3):

In principle, the source for it is available. You *could* copy it, compile it and create a jar usable with Java 8 (possibly with some changes or missing features if the code needs Java 9 anywhere), similarly to [ThreeTen-Backport providing `java.time` for Java 6/7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

But there doesn't seem to be one available yet (after a quick search). If you decide to go in this direction, make sure to follow the relevant licenses.

Comment: I tried to copy the source code from jdk9 and compiled it, but it failed with some missing internal API.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: Just for fun, I've attempted such a [backport](https://github.com/stefan-zobel/http2client-java8) not so long ago. In principle, I'd say it works though I'd still consider its status as experimental.